# Intellij project migration from *.iml to pom.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, project, pom.xml

I have a Intellij Idea maven project. All dependency added through

> Project Structure -> Libraries -> New project library -> from Maven

[image]

So, all dependencies stored in `*.iml` file. Now I need to transfer them from `.iml` to `pom.xml` (`iml` file should not be included to a version control system). What is the best way to accomplish the task

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching it from the wrong direction. It would be much easier to just update the `pom.xml` file (IntelliJ IDEA has pretty neat completions and intellisense around it) and allow IntelliJ to sync from it instead of starting with the `iml` file and then update the `pom.xml` from it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain, how can I update  `pom.xml` in my project?

Comment: @Loom I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you elaborate what exactly you're asking?

Comment: My not native Englsh fails me. I have a project, with dependencies were added as it shown on the picture. From my understanding it means that all project lib dependencies are stored in `.iml`. Now `pom.xml` file is empty and `.iml` is full. I've been infromed `.iml` are not allowed in our vcs storage. So, I need to keep project dependencies in `pom.xml`. I would like to find some way to fill `pom.xml` with dependencies that I already added as shown on the image. I hope there is some way to accomplish it other than manually fill `pom.xml`. I would like to find out this way.

Comment: @Loom If you already have an `.iml` file, I'm not aware of a way to generate `pom.xml` dependencies from it, sorry.